# Redirect 10 second Countdown

Tags: php, html, redirect

I have a page which redirects a user after 10 seconds with the following code.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="10;URL=login.php">
```

I then have this code which is echo'd in PHP, and would **like the "10" (seconds) to countdown dynamically as 10, 9, 8, 7... so the user can see the seconds left until the page redirects.**

```
echo "We cant find you on the system. <br/> Please return to the <b><a href='login.php'>Login</a></b> page and ensure that <br/>you have entered your details correctly. 
<br>
<br>
<b>Warning</b>: You willl be redirected  back to the Login Page <br> in <b>10 Seconds</b>";
```

I was wondering if there was a way that this can be done in PHP, if not what would be the best way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The following will redirect the user right away to `login.php`

```
<?php
header('Location: login.php'); // redirects the user instantaneously.
exit;
?>
```

You can use the following to delay the redirection by X seconds but there is no graphical countdown (thanks to [user1111929](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1111929/user1111929)):

```
<?php
header('refresh: 10; url=login.php'); // redirect the user after 10 seconds
#exit; // note that exit is not required, HTML can be displayed.
?>
```

If you want a graphical countdown, here's a sample code in JavaScript:

```
<p>You will be redirected in <span id="counter">10</span> second(s).</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function countdown() {
    var i = document.getElementById('counter');
    if (parseInt(i.innerHTML)<=0) {
        location.href = 'login.php';
    }
    if (parseInt(i.innerHTML)!=0) {
        i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)-1;
    }
}
setInterval(function(){ countdown(); },1000);
</script>
```

Comment: is there any way that in the echo statement, the "10" can count down dynamically? 10, 9, 8, 7..? thanks

Comment: No, thats not possible. Just use the javascript solution i provided to you. Then use Jquery to do a dynamic countdown.

Comment: i updated my answer. you need JavaScript to do the countdown for you.

Comment: i have got the script working(ish) however the counter goes straight from "10" to "0". can you see a quick fix? i have never done javascript before

Comment: It is not correct that you cannot delay a redirect in php. Something like `header('refresh: 10; url=login.php');` works perfectly (but of course does not do a graphical countdown).

Answer (score 8):

I would use javascript for this

```
var counter = 10;
setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if(counter < 0) {
        window.location = 'login.php';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = counter;
         }
}, 1000);​
```

Update:
http://jsfiddle.net/6wxu3/1/

Answer (score 7):

You cannot do this with pure PHP - but javascript is your friend here.

Change your HTML to put the number of seconds in a `span`:

```
<b><span id="count">10</span> Seconds</b>
```

Then remove your `meta` tag and use this javascript:

```
var count = 10;
function decrement() {
    count--;
    if(count == 0) {
        window.location = 'login.php';
    }
    else {
        document.findElementById("count").innerHTML = "" + count;
        setTimeout("decrement", 1000);
    }
}
setTimeout("decrement", 1000);
```

This will decrement the count on the page every second and then redirect to `login.php` when the counter reaches 0.

Answer (score 1):

`header("Refresh: 2; url=$your_url");`

Remember not to put any html content before the header.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer should give a reason. It correctly answers the OP's question.

Comment: This is not correct, the question was to decrement the 10, not to redirect with php

Comment: The question was modified after this answer was posted. The [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12498209/revisions) is not very clear that a dynamic countdown must be displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty fine for 3 seconds redirect page redirect to the index page but does not display the countdown timer on the screen.

```
<?php
    echo "New record has been added successfully ! This page will redirect in 3 seconds";
    header('refresh: 3; url=index.php');
?>
```