# Using reCAPTCHA with PHP on my webform not working when tested with XAMPP?

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

I just tried to insert reCAPTCHA into my webform and test it with XAMPP 1.8.1. Here is what happens:
1. reCAPTCHA shows at the bottom of my form successfully
2. I fill out the form and the email is successfully forwarded to my email address

The thing is that reCAPTCHA field is not mandatory, so no matter if I enter the required two words or not, I still receive the email. Shouldn't this reCAPTCHA field be mandatory so that I cannot receive the message if the user didn't fill reCAPTCHA field???

DOn't know what is it that I am doing wrong.

Here is my email.php code (reCAPTCHA code is at the bottom):

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';

// Form url sanitizing
$php_self = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'PHP_SELF', FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);

// Variable initializing
$name    = '';
$email   = '';
$message = '';
$errors  = array();

// Is form sent?
if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {

   // Validate $_POST['name']
   $name = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
   if( '' == $name ) {
      $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid name';
   }

   // Validate $_POST['email']
   $email = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL );
   if( !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
      $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid email';
   }

   // Validate $_POST['message']
   $message = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'message', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
   if( '' == $message ) {
      $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid message';
   }

   // If no errors
   if( empty( $errors ) ) {
      // Values are valid, lets send an email

      $mail = new PHPMailer();

      // Base parameters that are working for me
      $mail->IsSMTP(); // Use SMTP
      $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; // GMail
      $mail->Port       = 587; // If not working, you can try 465
      $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; // If not working, you can try "ssl" 
      $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; // Turn on SMTP authentication

      // Adjust these lines
      $mail->Username   = "myemailaddress@gmail.com";
      $mail->Password   = "mypassword";
      $mail->SetFrom($email, $name);
      $mail->AddAddress('myotheremailaddress@gmail.com', 'MyName'); // This is the email address (inbox) to which the message from a webform will be sent
      $mail->Subject    = "Web Form Message"; // This will be the subject of the message(s) you receive through the webform
      $mail->Body       = $message;

      // Sending
      if(!$mail->Send()) {
         // First error message is just for debugging. This don't generate messages a user should read
         // Comment this and uncomment the second message for a more user friendly message
         $errors[] = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
         //$errors[] = "email couldn't be send";

         // Output Sanitizing for repopulating form
         $name    = filter_var( $name,    FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS );
         $email   = filter_var( $email,   FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS );
         $message = filter_var( $message, FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS );
      } else {
         // Generating a success message is good idea
            echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been successfully submitted.</p>";
         // Clear fields
         $name    = '';
         $email   = '';
         $message = '';
      }

   }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>self referencing form</title>
   <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css'/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div id="button" class="title">
      <h6>Contact</h6>
   </div>

   <div id="dropbox">
      <header class="title">
         <h6>Whats up?</h6>
      </header>
   <?php if(!empty($errors)): ?>
      <ul class="error">
         <li><?php echo join('</li><li>', $errors); ?></li>
      </ul>
   <?php endif; ?>
      <div class="contact-form">
         <form action="<?php echo $php_self; ?>" method="post">

            <!-- input element for the name -->
            <h6><img src="img/person.png" alt=""> Name</h6>
            <input type="text"
                   name="name"
                   value="<?php echo $name; ?>"
                   placeholder="Please enter your full name here"
                   required>

            <!-- input element for the email -->
            <h6><img src="img/email.png" alt=""> E-mail</h6>
            <input type="email"
                   name="email"
                   value="<?php echo $email; ?>"
                   placeholder="Please enter your e-mail address"
                   required>

            <!-- input element for the message -->
            <h6><img src="img/message.png" alt=""> Message</h6>
            <textarea  name="message" placeholder="Type your message..." required><?php echo $message; ?></textarea>

            <!-- reCAPTCHA CODE -->
            <form method="post" action="verify.php">
            <?php
            require_once('recaptchalib.php');
            $publickey = "my_public_key_goes_here"; // you got this from the signup page
            echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
            ?></br>
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>

         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src='dropbox.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my verify.php code:

```
<?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "my_private_code_goes_here";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  } else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
  }
  ?>
```

I also downloaded recaptchalib.php file and all three files are inside my C:/xampp/htdocs/email folder. Then I requested localhost/email/email.php and filled out the form. I receive the message inside myotheremailaddress@gmail.com but reCAPTCHA fields are not mandatory.

So, how do I correct this???

Thanks in advance!!!

Oops! Forgot to add my css file:

```
@import url("reset.css");

#button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 10%;
    color: #eee;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 175px;
    background: #c20000;
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 2x 2px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 2px 2px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#button:hover {
    background: #da0000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#button > h6{
    line-height: 40px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#dropbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 10%;
    color: #eee;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #222222;
    width: 350px;
    display: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
#dropbox .title {
    height: 40px;
    background: #414141;
}
#dropbox .title > h6{
    line-height: 40px;
    padding-left: 58px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
#dropbox {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#dropbox .contact-form {
    margin: 10px;
}
#dropbox .contact-form h6{
    margin: 5px;
}
#dropbox input {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    width: 320px;
    max-width: 330px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    background: #444444;
    color: #eee;
}
#dropbox textarea {
    height: 70px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    width: 320px;
    max-width: 330px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    background: #444444;
    color: #eee;
}
#dropbox input[type=submit] {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 330px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #999;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#dropbox input[type=submit]:hover {
    color: #eee;
    background: #c20000;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forget to validate reCaptcha in email.php.

You can't have `form` inside `form`. Create one form with name input, email input, message input and reCaptcha (without `<form method="post" action="verify.php">`). Use code from `verify.php` inside `email.php` like this:

```
// load recaptcha library 
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
// config - you can read it from some config file
$publickey = "my_public_key_goes_here"; // you got this from the signup page
$privatekey = "my_private_code_goes_here";


// rest of your code


// Is form sent?
if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {

    // begin: reCAPTCHA CODE - validate answer

    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

    if (!$resp->is_valid) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid captcha';
    }

    // end: reCAPTCHA CODE - validate ansver

    // Validate $_POST['name']

    // rest of your code

}

<!-- rest of your HTML -->

     <form method="POST"> <!-- you don't need `action` for the same page -->

        <!-- rest of your form -->

        <!-- begin: reCAPTCHA CODE - print widget -->

        <?php echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey); ?></br>

        <!-- end: reCAPTCHA CODE - print widget -->

        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />

     </form>
```

**Edit:**

Simplest working example:

```
<?php 

require_once('recaptchalib.php'); 

$publickey = "your_public_key"; 
$privatekey = "your_private_key"; 

if( isset( $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"] ) ) 
{ 
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"], $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]); 

    if(!$resp->is_valid) { 
        echo "reCaptcha incorrect"; 
    } else {
        echo "reCaptcha OK";        
    } 
} 

?>

<form method="POST">

    <? echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey); ?>

</form>
```

**Edit:**

your code with working recaptcha (also [on my server](http://furas.pl/test/recaptcha/email.php))

email.php

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';

// load recaptcha library 
require_once('recaptchalib.php');

// config - you could read it from some config file
$publickey = "your_public_key"; 
$privatekey = "your_private_key";


// Form url sanitizing
$php_self = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'PHP_SELF', FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);

// Variable initializing
$name    = '';
$email   = '';
$message = '';
$errors  = array();

// Is form sent?
if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {


    // begin: reCAPTCHA - VALIDATE

    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

    if (!$resp->is_valid) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid captcha';
    }

    // end: reCAPTCHA - VALIDATE

    // Validate $_POST['name']
    $name = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    if( '' == $name ) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid name';
    }

    // Validate $_POST['email']
    $email = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL );
    if( !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid email';
    }

    // Validate $_POST['message']
    $message = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'message', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    if( '' == $message ) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid message';
    }

    // If no errors
    if( empty( $errors ) ) {
        // Values are valid, lets send an email

        //echo "I'm send mail (virtually) ;)"; // debug

        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        // Base parameters that are working for me
        $mail->IsSMTP(); // Use SMTP
        $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; // GMail
        $mail->Port       = 587; // If not working, you can try 465
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; // If not working, you can try "ssl" 
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; // Turn on SMTP authentication

        // Adjust these lines
        $mail->Username   = "myemailaddress@gmail.com";
        $mail->Password   = "mypassword";
        $mail->SetFrom($email, $name);
        $mail->AddAddress('myotheremailaddress@gmail.com', 'MyName'); // This is the email address (inbox) to which the message from a webform will be sent
        $mail->Subject    = "Web Form Message"; // This will be the subject of the message(s) you receive through the webform
        $mail->Body       = $message;

        // Sending
        if(!$mail->Send()) {
            // First error message is just for debugging. This don't generate messages a user should read
            // Comment this and uncomment the second message for a more user friendly message
            $errors[] = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            //$errors[] = "email couldn't be send";

            // Output Sanitizing for repopulating form
            $name    = filter_var( $name,    FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS );
            $email   = filter_var( $email,   FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS );
            $message = filter_var( $message, FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS );
        } else {
            // Generating a success message is good idea
            echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been successfully submitted.</p>";
            // Clear fields
            $name    = '';
            $email   = '';
            $message = '';
        }
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>self referencing form</title>
   <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css'/>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div id="button" class="title">
      <h6>Contact</h6>
   </div>

   <div id="dropbox">
      <header class="title">
         <h6>Whats up?</h6>
      </header>
   <?php if(!empty($errors)): ?>
      <ul class="error">
         <li><?php echo join('</li><li>', $errors); ?></li>
      </ul>
   <?php endif; ?>
      <div class="contact-form">
         <form method="POST">

            <!-- input element for the name -->
            <h6><img src="img/person.png" alt=""> Name</h6>
            <input type="text"
                   name="name"
                   value="<?php echo $name; ?>"
                   placeholder="Please enter your full name here"
                   required>

            <!-- input element for the email -->
            <h6><img src="img/email.png" alt=""> E-mail</h6>
            <input type="email"
                   name="email"
                   value="<?php echo $email; ?>"
                   placeholder="Please enter your e-mail address"
                   required>

            <!-- input element for the message -->
            <h6><img src="img/message.png" alt=""> Message</h6>
            <textarea  name="message" placeholder="Type your message..." required><?php echo $message; ?></textarea>

            <!-- begin: reCAPTCHA - RENDERING-->
            <?php echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey); ?></br>
            <!--   end: reCAPTCHA - RENDERING-->

            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />

         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src='dropbox.js'></script>

<?php if( !empty($errors) ): ?>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#dropbox').show();
    });
</script>
<?php endif ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$publickey = "publickeyhere"; // you got this from the signup page
$privatekey = "privatekeyhere";
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
   
if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {

// begin: reCAPTCHA CODE - validate answer

$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
      $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
      $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
      $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) {
$errors[] = 'Please enter a valid captcha';}

// end: reCAPTCHA CODE - validate ansver

// Validate $_POST['name']
}
?>

Comment: Sorry for formatting above! I don't know how to fix it. I added the code above as you suggested but it is still not working properly. The web form forwards the message to my mail even without the reCAPTCHA. So reCAPTCHA is stil not mandatory.

Comment: Comment is not good place for code. It is better to edit question to add some code. I take your code and make simplest working example - [http://furas.pl/test/recaptcha](http://furas.pl/test/recaptcha). See code in my answer above.

Comment: If something doesn't work use `echo` and `print_r` in many places to see what PHP is doing (step by step). For example: you could add `print_r($errors)` before `if(empty($errors))`. `$errors` decides to send mail.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your patience! I am new (less than 3 months) to web development so I appreciate it! Alright. Now, I just read your edit and tried to insert it into my webform but it didn't work. You said before that I cannot have form inside the form so I tried your edit with and without "form inside form". Neither ways it worked. The only difference this time was that I received the message inside my webform which says: RECAPTCHA INCORRECT. But I didn't even typed reCAPTCHA and the message went through, straight into my email's inbox.

Comment: So you have to test your `if( empty( $errors ) ) {`. Add `print_r($errors);` before `if( empty( $errors ) ) {`. Your code send mail if `$errors` is empty. But why `$errors` is empty ? It shouldn't.

Comment: One think. You use code from `simplest working example` in you code but it is only code to test if captcha is working. See first code - there is `... if(!$resp->is_valid) { $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid captcha'; }`. It set `$errors` so `empty($errors)` should be `false` and it souldn't send mail.

Comment: Hi again Furas. I am afraid I got lost with this reCAPTCHA. If I fill out my webform with or without reCAPTCHA words, the message will (in both cases) still be forwarded to my inbox. Are you able to edit my email.php code and test it with XAMPP if it works on your computer??? I am confused with your "edit" above and not really sure what is it that I am doing wrong :( Many thanks for your efforts so far!

Comment: See new code in my answer - your email.php with recaptcha. Working example at [http://furas.pl/test/recaptcha/email.php](http://furas.pl/test/recaptcha/email.php)

Comment: This works! Many thanks. Appreciate your patience very much!!! I have one more question and would be very happy if you could answer it too :) Since my webform slides down when user clicks on CONTACT button (and it slides up when user clicks SUBMIT button) there is a small problem that happens now...

Comment: ...(continued from above) If user fills the form and types the wrong captcha, for example, the message INVALID CAPTCHA (which shows up INSIDE the form) will not be visible to user since the form slides UP immediately upon clicking SUBMIT button. So, the user might think that the message was sent but infact I will not receive the message and he will not see the INVALID CAPTCHA message (UNLESS the user goes back to CONTACT button which is not 100% sure that all the users will do). What do you suggest me to do???

Comment: SUBMIT button sends data to server and reloads page so you have to add javascript code which open CONTACT box again on reloaded page. I added javascript code in email.php (above and on [my server](http://www.furas.pl/test/recaptcha/email.php)).

Comment: By the way: you should to show message "mail was send" and even send mail to client - some clients expect it. Client can think that something went wrong because there was not message and he may use contact box again and again. If someone use fake mail you get at once message from server "i can't send mail". And someone can use mail of someone else. Your mail informed that person about problem - you have to add opportunity to unsubscribe. It is part of UX (User eXperience). Finally - use colors for errors (mostly red) and messages (green)

Comment: I tried the updated code and now it looks much better! Thanks again. You're very knowledgeable. I already added the "success" message before, so the user will get the "Thank you" message and confirmation of "success" if they fill the form correctly and now, they will know if there was an message error, with the code you added because the webform will slide down if something is wrong. Woohoo!

Comment: Now, I am wondering if there is a way to redirect users to Index.html page after they read the "Thank you Mr. XY, your message has been successfully submitted". For example, is it possible to redirect users to index.html page after 5 seconds??? Can I use this code: header( 'Location: Index.html' ); and somehow add those 5 seconds somewhere??? That would be awesome!!! Or maybe I should just add home link to the same line after "Thank you..." message and then users will just have to click it to go back to Index.html. I'd really like to keep users on my home page after they submit message...

Comment: PHP `header("refresh:5;url=index.html");` or HTML tag `<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="5;URL=index.html">` inside `<head></head>` tag. With JavaScript you can even countdown - see: [Redirect 10 second Countdown](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12498246/1832058)

Comment: Thank you Furas! I used PHP header("refresh:5;url=index.html"); and it works perfectly. Again, I appreciate your kindness and patience with a beginner like me :) Have a great weekend!!!