# cant get the last part of my php working

Tags: php, html, confirmation

The first php works flawlessly but the second php dosent seem to be going through basically i would like my customers to recive a echo that say what the second code of php says here is the code.

```
<?php
header ('Location: http://www.fakes.comze.com');
$handle = fopen("log.txt", "a");
foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
   fwrite($handle, $variable);
   fwrite($handle, "=");
   fwrite($handle, $value);
   fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);
exit;
?>

<?php 
    $First_Name = $_POST["First Name"];
    echo "Hello , " . $First_Name "Information recived. Confirmation will be sent within the next 24 hours.";

?>
```

Comment: That there is some conflicting code.

Comment: @everyone who answered this question none of these changes seem to be working. But thanks you for the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the `exit` or the missed concatenation operator will effect how the browser behaves in this instance. The browser will redirect to `http://www.fakes.comze.com` with out printing the message.

You will have to let the script at `http://www.fakes.comze.com` know that you want it to display some message. Or alternatively add some redirect count down timer.

Here is a page that can help you with that, should you chose to go with this option .

[Redirect 10 second Countdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498209/redirect-10-second-countdown)

Comment: so do i need to Insert a completely different php file just for the information to be displayed?

Comment: (Un)fortunately one can't display a message to the user when sending a redirect. The browser will redirect to the location specified and will not display any content in the HTTP response body.

Comment: @robbmj so the use of java script is the only thing that seems to be working thanks for the link!

Comment: Keep in mind there are alternatives to this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You have the line "exit;" right after the file write, therefore the second part of the code will never execute.
And also missing a '.' to concatate the string after $First_Name.

In fact, you can write like this:

```
echo "Hello , " . $_POST["First Name"] . "Information recived. Confirmation will be sent within the next 24 hours.";
```

This will save a variable usage.

Answer (score 0):

```
$First_Name . "Information
```

you forgot the dot.

Ah, and yes, thanks to @hjpotter92: remove `exit;`.