# redirect based on url with countdown timer

Tags: javascript

I have a website with a url1  - we have now re-branded and have added url2 to the site.

What I would like is a landing page that tells users they are being redirected from url1 to url2 when they go to url1 with a 10 second countdown.

If a user goes to url2 then they are redirected straight away to that site.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, what have you tried or looked into so far? ....for instance a quick google has given me loads of useful information about a simple way of achieving this in PHP - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498209/redirect-10-second-countdown here is another - http://www.apphp.com/index.php?snippet=javascript-redirect-with-timer

Comment: Use some countdown plugin like http://flipclockjs.com/faces/daily-counter and on end use window.location.href = url2; The end.

Comment: You can immediately redirect to a site, but not without first arriving at your url2.  It would be more efficient to change server configuration so that when url2 is requested, it will simply forward you to new site and it will be like navigating to the right page to begin with.